# $fieldset->addType() show extra textbox in admin form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminform, custom-field, fieldsets

I used this code for add custom field type on admin form

```
$fieldset->addType('uploadedfile', '\Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\filerenderer\Renderer\FileIconAdmin');

$fieldset->addField(
    'Uploaded File',
    'uploadedfile',
    [
        'name'  => 'uploadedfile',
        'label' => __('Custom Div'),
        'title' => __('Custom Div'),

    ]
);
```

But it's display extra textbox field in admin Form, How we remove this extra textbox?

[image]

File: Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\filerenderer\Renderer\FileIconAdmin.php

```
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\filerenderer\Renderer;

class FileIconAdmin extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    public function getAfterElementHtml()
    {
        // here you can write your code.
        $customDiv = '<div style="width:600px;height:200px;margin:10px 0;border:2px solid #000" id="customdiv"><h1 style="margin-top: 12%;margin-left:40%;">Custom Div</h1></div>';
        return $customDiv;
    }
}
```

Comment: how does `\Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\filerenderer\Renderer\FileIconAdmin` look like?

Comment: Please check Marius I edit question with FileIconAdmin.php file

Comment: You need to use `getElementHtml` in place  of `getAfterElementHtml`

Comment: It's Perfact! But Field label not display

Comment: Your code is correct. It should show you the Label for the field, not sure what can cause this issue. I have checked with same code it the label is there.